# Estructura correcta para WITH en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
;WITH TABLA1 AS (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_EMPLEADOS, 
TERRITORIO
FROM AR_EMPLEADOS
WHERE ANIO = 2018
AND TERRITORIO = 'A'
GROUP BY TERRITORIO
)

;WITH TABLA2 AS (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_PRODUCTOS,
TERRITORIO
FROM AR_PRODUCTOS
WHERE ANIO = 2018
AND TERRITORIO = 'A'
GROUP BY TERRITORIO
)

SELECT A.TERRITORIO,
A.TOTAL_EMPLEADOS,
B.AR_PRODUCTOS
FROM TABLA1 A
INNER JOIN TABLA2 B ON A.TERRITORIO = B.TERRITORIO
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer si es posible con la sentencia `WITH` ?

Comment: Porque tienes `;` antes del `WITH`?

Comment: Por que si no agrego el ; no me funciona el WITH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar múltiples" **common table expression** las sintaxis adecuada es:

```
;WITH T1 AS (...), T2 AS (..) SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON ...
```

Por ejemplo:

```
;
WITH 
t1 as (select * from sysobjects),
t2 as (select * from syscolumns)

select *
    from t1
    inner join t2
        on t1.id = t2.id
```

Y en tu caso:

```
;WITH TABLA1 AS (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_EMPLEADOS, 
TERRITORIO
FROM AR_EMPLEADOS
WHERE ANIO = 2018
AND TERRITORIO = 'A'
GROUP BY TERRITORIO
),
TABLA2 AS (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_PRODUCTOS,
TERRITORIO
FROM AR_PRODUCTOS
WHERE ANIO = 2018
AND TERRITORIO = 'A'
GROUP BY TERRITORIO
)

SELECT A.TERRITORIO,
A.TOTAL_EMPLEADOS,
B.AR_PRODUCTOS
FROM TABLA1 A
INNER JOIN TABLA2 B ON A.TERRITORIO = B.TERRITORIO
```

Answer (score 0):

la sintaxis correcta sería

```
WITH TABLA1 (TOTAL_EMPLEADOS, TERRITORIO) 
AS 
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_EMPLEADOS, 
TERRITORIO
FROM AR_EMPLEADOS
WHERE ANIO = 2018
AND TERRITORIO = 'A'
GROUP BY TERRITORIO
)
```

PD: el punto y coma `;` es para ejecutar varias sentencias, si no tienes ninguna sentencia antes del primer *WITH* me parece que no te funcionará. Dicho de otra forma

[SQL Statement] ;

[SQL Statement] ;

[SQL Statement] ;

[SQL Statement] ;

[SQL Statement] ;

[SQL Statement] ;